# Getting frame ID from puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

In the Frame Object class for Puppeteer, there is .name() method which does the following:

"If the name is empty, returns the id attribute instead."

However is there a way to get the frame ID using Frame object of puppeteer in cases where name() is not suitable?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can use [`page.frames()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageframes) to get an array of all frames attached to the page.

Alternatively, you can use [`page.mainFrame()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagemainframe) to get the page's main frame.

Then, you can access the [Frame ID](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#type-FrameId) using one of the following methods:

```
page.frames()[0]._id
page.mainFrame()._id
```

Comment: This is not the HTML ID, this give you an internal ID, something like A37932E32C72B658BE9A6C444DE90031